# using javascript to fill container div with children, it only works half the time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm going through the odin project, and the first project is to make an etchesketch javascript program that has several functions. one of the rules is to use javascript to create a user defined value of containers in the etchesketch, and to have them change size to fit in the defined container size.

the code i've written fills in the container perfectly up  until a user defines a size larger than 32. not really sure why the container doesnt fill with divs after that.

any suggestions? i've been stuck for a day on this damn thing. its giving me a migrane.

Here is a link to the git-hub repo: [Etchesketch Project](https://github.com/nickolaskg/odin_proj/tree/master/etchesketch)

Comment: just created a fiddle. your code works fine in 128 http://jsfiddle.net/j9f10js9/

Comment: are the blocks on the screen after the user inputs the selection? then the events are not firing?

Comment: I think it's hard to see the problem because the container has a very light background color. If you change the color of the container background to black, you can see when the divs are generated, they dont completely fill the container. when the div grid size is 16-32 it works fine, but after that, the gap at  the bottom of the container grows.